# Real TIme Map Update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using google maps and the Location services of android however even though when I am moving the device the method is not updating the ui. I have requested permission to use the location I would have presumed when I moved the device that the

locationObtained would have got the updated information of the lat and long when the user moved the device but this only appears to get it once.

```
double lat=0.00;
double lng=0.00;
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    if (await CrossPermissions.Current.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationaleAsync(Permission.Location))
    {
         await DisplayAlert("Need location", "Gunna need that location", "OK                     
    }
    var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
         status = results[Permission.Location];
}
if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
    ILocation loc = DependencyService.Get<ILocation>();
    loc.locationObtained += (object ss, ILocationEventArgs ee) =>
    {
         loc.ObtainMyLocation();
         lat = ee.lat;
         lng = ee.lng;

         lbllat.Text = ee.lat.ToString();
         lbllong.Text = ee.lng.ToString();

    };
        Position position = new Position(lat, lng);
        map.Pins.Add(_pinTokyo2);    

    }
}
```

This is the class I use to get the location using the dependency service.

```
namespace Fitnessbudy.Droid
{
    public class LocationEventArgs : EventArgs, ILocationEventArgs
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetMyLocation : Java.Lang.Object, ILocation, ILocationListener
    {
        public event EventHandler<ILocationEventArgs> locationObtained;

        public void ObtainMyLocation()
        {
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
            lm.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NetworkProvider, 0, 0, this);

        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            if (location != null)
            {
                LocationEventArgs args = new LocationEventArgs();
                args.lat = location.Latitude;
                args.lng = location.Longitude;
                locationObtained(this, args);
            }
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.fitnessbudy" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="Fitnessbudy.Android"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
</manifest>
```

I made sure that I was in release mode. So that permission is granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `loc.ObtainMyLocation` is inside the callback and thus your location updates are not initialized.

```
~~~
ILocation loc = DependencyService.Get<ILocation>();
loc.locationObtained += (object ss, ILocationEventArgs ee) =>
{
     lat = ee.lat;
     lng = ee.lng;

     lbllat.Text = ee.lat.ToString();
     lbllong.Text = ee.lng.ToString();

};
loc.ObtainMyLocation();
~~~
```

Comment: I treid that but its still not updating the UI

Comment: When I move my position it does not change and then event doest get fired according to my loggin

Comment: @rogue39nin Your `LocationManager lm` variable is local and "assuming it is getting GC'd. Move it to a class level variable.

Comment: Was such a dummy location was disabled on the testing device even though i granted permission. Forgot i turned it off testing